# PDFTK and PHP exec

Tags: php, shell, command, pdftk

My question is, for some reason when I execute the pdftk command to fill a form through PHP, I get an error from pdftk that it can't find the file. I copy the command and paste it on the terminal and it works fine. I am using full paths for the program and the files locations. Any idea what I can do to fix this problem and be able to execute it from the PHP script? I'm using Ubuntu and got the pdftk from the Ubuntu repos.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out. Using dirname and **FILE** fixed my problem.

Comment: You should be more descriptive,as i am facing same issue. But your answer is not helping..

Comment: It was basically me having a wrong path. Check that your paths are correct. Ended up using something like dirname(__FILE__), etc how many folders up add dirname around. My case my a little different because I needed a specific part of the path.